# What is the significance of Mona Lisa in the Rocky Horror Picture Show?

Tags: rocky-horror-picture-show

What is the significance of Mona Lisa in the *Rocky Horror Picture Show*? The painting shows up everywhere - it is there during time warp and also in the final scenes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apparently it's simply intended to show that Frank, while cultured, has a
very *twisted* appreciation of art. According to the film's production designer Brian Thompson their thinking was that ***Frank loved the Mona Lisa so much that he got a bunch of copies of it and shoved them all over his house, not really caring that they were low quality repros.***

> *“I imagined that **Frank [N. Furter] had an insight into art he had seen, maybe in
> books or movies or somewhere and decided he wanted.”** For a moment
> Thomson becomes Frank soliciting the Mona Lisa from the Louvre: **“maybe
> a picture of that woman. We’ll have two of those.”***
>
> ***“To Frank it wouldn’t matter if they are black and white Xeroxes
> facing opposite ways.** I may still have all the letters that I wrote
> from Frank to the Louvre and places. There are also letters between
> Frank and the local authorities regarding noisy motorcycles and a
> strange blue glow coming from his house. They’re never seen in the
> film but everything was totally authentic.”*
>
> <sub><sup>[Brian Thomson interview - Crazed Imaginations](http://www.rockypedia.org/Brian_Thomson_interview_-_Crazed_Imaginations)</sup></sub>

Answer (score 4):

#### Frank seems to appreciate great works of art.

This is one of many references to famous works of art in *Rocky Horror Picture Show*.  Others include:

[image]
[The Creation of Adam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Creation_of_Adam) by Michelangelo

[image] [image]
[Arrangement in Grey and Black No .1 (aka "Whistler's Mother")](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whistler%27s_Mother) by James Whistler - this is actually a photo recreation of the painting, and Meatloaf is posing as Whistler's mom

[image] [image]
[American Gothic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Gothic) by Grant Wood

[image]
[The Discobolus of Myron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discobolus)

[image]
Two copies of Michelangelo's [David](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_(Michelangelo))

[image]
[The Kiss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Kiss_(Rodin_sculpture)) by Auguste Rodin

[image]
[The Last Supper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_Supper_(Leonardo_da_Vinci)) by Leonardo Da Vinci

[image]
[Aphrodite of Melos (aka Venus de Milo)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venus_de_Milo), and another [Capitoline Aphrodite/Venus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitoline_Venus) -
possibly [Aphrodite of Menophantos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aphrodite_of_Menophantos)